Check characters typed on an Ubuntu encrypted system
I have a computer at home and I am regularly on the go and therefore decided to fully encrypt my Ubuntu LTS 22.04. I know the password and have currently to problem whatsoever to have full access to my computer. However, I remember a few situations on my previous computer (a macbook) where I suddenly struggled to type the correct password. Looking ahead, I am projecting myself into a similar situation and would like to have the possibility to have a visual feedback of what I am typing. Therefore, here is my first question:

in case of several wrong attempts to type a password, is there a way to see and check character typed when entering passphrase for a Ubuntu encrypted system (similar to the "eye" often located on the right side of the password bar to login as user, to unmask the "dots" typed in to the bar)
If the answer to 1 is "No", is it because there is a legitimate security reason for this? or is it because the feature was just not implemented?



Can you open up a terminal (or web browser or whatever), type the password in and copy and paste it into this box?  It's possible that the keys are mapped differently now from when you first entered it (presumably during installation).

Thank you for your comment @Ray. No I can't: that is the first thing appearing after boot loader

No. There is very little support for unauthorized users.

possibly related as a solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

thank you for your comment @graham. Unfortunately booting with advanced options does not allow to have more visual feedback on what is being typed

Thank you for your comment @waltinator, as pointed in the edited question: the reason why this is not possible is that there is a legitimate security reason for this or is it because the feature was just not implemented?

I don't think you understood the reason for the link I posted. If you are having trouble with your existing password, you can reset it - the comment was not intended to answer you specific request to see what you typed - hence the comment not an answer.

thanks a lot @graham: indeed your advice was very good: it allows to boot on an usb drive and decrypt the disk with visual feedback there. I would be glad to accept such an answer if you want to write one

happy to do that of course but you might prefer to answer your own question on that basis, accept it (in 48 hours) and gain some valuable rep for doing so. Let me know when you have done so and I will upvote accordingly.

@graham I have done as you told me. Thank you again for the support

Thanks to the adice of @graham a working solution is boot on an usb drive, select the keyboard and decrypt the disk with visual feedback there.
